# Piem validator programme

Tags: code-golf, pi

Write a program that defines a function that can check if a string variable called "anything you want or inputted by the user" is or not a piem.
(piem =  a story or poem in which the word lengths represent the digits of π ([from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piphilology#Examples_in_English)))

Some examples:

```
myfunction("I am clearly wrong") # False
myfunction("How I want a drink, alcoholic of course, after the heavy lectures involving quantum mechanics") #True (Taken from Wikipedia)
myfunction("Law ' s fine") # True
```

You should delete any kind of punctuation or newline before processing.
Pure code golf, the shortest wins

## End date: evening of 1/10/2014

## Various answers

- How many digits do we need to handle? **More than 10**
- As a matter of interest, how should 0's in PI be interpreted? Skipped or 10 letter words? **As 10 letters words**
- "a variable called piem" – so the name of the parameter must be piem? **No, it hasn't, question text corrected**
- A fun bonus might be a solution that is itself a piem **If your solution is a piem you get *0.5 bonus**
- For the sake of argument, is **_** always punctuation? **You can decide if it is punctuation or if it isn't**
- It's unclear what is meant by "any kind of punctuation" **I mean ,.'"?!;;()**
- So digits should be counted? And Law's fine would be false? **Digits should be treated as letters, Law's fine = False; Law ' s fine = True**

## Comments

- The APL solution should be counted in Bytes
- **If your solution works for 100+ digits of pi you get *0.8 bonus**
- Because of the great interest the end date is one day more in the future.

Comment: How many digits do we need to handle?

Comment: So digits should be counted? And `Law's fine` would be false?

Comment: "a variable called piem" – so the name of the parameter *must* be `piem`? That renders all current answers incorrect.

Comment: Also, should new lines really be removed instead of treated like spaces. Because that means that `How\nI\nwant` yields false but `A\nB\nC` yields true.

Comment: A fun bonus might be a solution that is itself a piem.

Comment: Validating for length (i.e. `[3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,...]`) is interesting and a good challenge, but validating a **piem**, I think, requires that the string actually be a story or a poem.  i.e. something with some sense or memorability to it.  It will be interesting to see how that requirement is handled.  For example, this, despite having appropriate length words, is *not* a piem in my opinion:  `"Bob I door I fence parameter an yellow fence red"`

Comment: I didn't mean to be overly negative in my previous comment -- I actually think this is a great challenge, particularly if the number of digits of pi is unconstrained.  I just think this isn't really about *piems*, which require *some* degree of sense to be memorable.  e.g. also not a piem: `"aaa a aaaa a aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaa aaaaa aaa"`

Comment: As a matter of interest, how should 0's in PI be interpreted? Skipped or 10 letter words?

Comment: I don't see any mention of Unicode in the puzzle description...

Comment: It's kind of a shame that you don't reply to very important questions, yet you already edited in an end date.

Comment: @IngoBürk I now replied, look the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## APL (39)

```
{N≡(≢N←≢¨('\w+'⎕S'\0')⍵)↑⍎¨'_. '~⍨99⍕○1}
```

It uses all the digits the APL interpreter's pi constant provides, to a limit of 99. In my case (Dyalog APL 14 32-bit) that was 16 digits. The 64-bit version likely has more digits. 16 digits is enough for the given examples to work, though.

Strings that have more than that amount of words will *fail*, even if all the digits it could check were true. (The same is true of other posts, as of this writing.) For example, if there were only 10 digits, the 'How I want a drink' one would fail. This can be fixed, but at the cost of 14 characters:

```
{(≢¨('\w+'⎕S'\0')⍵){∧/(⌊/≢¨⍺⍵)↑∨⌿⍺∘.=⍵}⍎¨'_. '~⍨99⍕○1}
```

That version will *accept* any string where the first *N* digits are correct.

Comment: Your code is the shortes but it is not Unicode... I'll have to think about if you deserve the win or not, the javascript version is just a little bit longer than this... Anyway I upvoted this answer.

Comment: @Caridorc a) Do you mean it's not ASCII? Because I'm pretty sure it's Unicode. b) What does the character encoding have to do with anything? APL is as valid a language as any other, it just uses an unconventional set of characters. The more relevant question is whether supporting only a limited amount of digits is valid or not, but you haven't replied to any requests for clarification on the actual challenge.

Comment: @marinus The question doesn't specify whether submissions should be scored by characters or bytes, but the default is bytes (as per the tag wiki), so I think your score is closer to 60.

Comment: Given the right encoding it's 1 byte per character. APL predates Unicode by decades after all.

Comment: @marinus Fair point! Do you know any particular (existing) encoding in which that would actually work?

Comment: @MartinBüttner: IBM codepage 907 is one, but there are loads.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript <strike>(169)(140)(137)(135)</strike> (63)for 17 digits of pi

In my version `Law's fine` and `Law ' s fine` return both true.

Newest Version (63) by Ingo Bürk and hsl

```
f=s=>!s.split(/\W+/).some((x,i)=>x.length-(Math.PI*1e16+'')[i])
```

New Version (135) for 17 digits of pi (Thanks to Ingo Bürk):

```
f=(s)=>{
s=s.split(/[!"#$%&'()*+, \-.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~]+/);
p=Math.PI*1e16+'';
    r=0;
    for(a=s.length;a--;)r+=s[a].length!=p[a];
    return !r
}
```

Old version (169) for 32 digits of pi:

```
f=(s)=>{
s=s.split(/[!"#$%&'()*+, \-.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~]+/);
p="31415926535897932384626433832795".split('');
    r=1;
    for(a=s.length;a--;)if(s[a].length!=p[a]){r=0};
    return r;
}
```

Comment: You can save 3 bytes with: ````1e15*Math.PI+"2384626433832795"````

Comment: Thanks=) In meantime i changed it using this idea but now only using the first 17 digits.

Comment: @IngoBürk Thank you very much, just checking what works.

Comment: Sorry, never mind. That doesn't seem to work. :/ The `for` loop can't be added this way.

Comment: But what does work is initializing `r=0` and then just looping over `r+=s[a].length!=p[a]` (you can omit the `;` in the end). Then, return `!r`.

Comment: I was just able to improve this, but you are right this willa gain save me 2 bytes I think.

Comment: It will probably be shorter to use `s.some(…)` instead of a for loop, too.

Comment: 114 bytes: f=(s)=>{p=Math.PI*1e16+'';return !s.split(/[!"#$%&'()*+, \-.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~]+/).some((x,i)=>x.length!=p[i])}

Comment: And 103 bytes: f=(s)=>!s.split(/[!"#$%&'()*+, \-.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~]+/).some((x,i)=>x.length!=(Math.PI*1e16+'')[i])

Comment: (Alternatively, omit the `!`, change `!=` to `==` and use `every` – same byte count)

Comment: I just tried it myself (it is commented now) and your last version, but it does not seem to work as expected? (I was not familiar with the `some` function: http://jsfiddle.net/dfk8k39L/1/

Comment: The backslashes got messed up. Take it from here: http://jsfiddle.net/dfk8k39L/2/

Comment: And finally 102 bytes. I don't think I can do any better now (except for the regexp): http://jsfiddle.net/dfk8k39L/3/

Comment: Any reason you can't use `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` for the split regex? Also, you can remove the parentheses around `s` in the function definition.

Comment: With @hsl's improvements this now comes down to 73 bytes: http://jsfiddle.net/dfk8k39L/4/

Comment: And using character classes, we get 63: http://jsfiddle.net/dfk8k39L/6/

Comment: I just add my answer using character classes and 'some'. All these comments were too much too read.

Comment: w00t, this is insane=) Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby, <strike>113</strike> <strike>101</strike> 79 (98 * 0.8)

```
require"bigdecimal/math"
x=->p{!(BigMath.PI(999).to_s[2..-1]!~/^#{p.scan(/\w+/).map(&:size)*''}/)}
```

### Explanation

- Input is taken as the argument to a lambda. It expects a `String`.
- Pi is calculated up to `999` decimals and turned into a String with the `.` removed.
- Punctuation marks are removed from the poem and it is split into individual words. `"Let's"` is counted as two words: `"Let"` and `"s"`.
- Use `Array#map` to convert each word to the size of the word, concatenate them into a `String`.
- Using a Regexp, check if the two created `String`s begin with the same characters.

I have applied the bonus for handling 100+ digits. `_` is not handled as punctuation in this solution.

Comment: Note that you're not treating `_` as punctuation.

Comment: Well spotted. For the sake of argument, is `_` *always* punctuation? What about sentences such as `My nickname on Stack Overflow is britishtea_500`.

Comment: It was just an observation. The OP isn't exactly specific about the details here.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll leave the answer up for now until it's specified in the problem :)

Comment: Using bigdecimal you have no limit on PI digits? Nice (+1)

Comment: You can specify the number of digits (it's a method, not a constant). I chose a limit of 999, so the program would execute reasonably fast and still be able to deal with bigger poems.

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 123 bytes * 0.8 = 98.4

```
f=#&@@RealDigits[Pi,10,Length[d=StringLength/@StringSplit@StringReplace[#,RegularExpression@"[!-.:-?]
"->""]/. 10->0]]==d&;
```

Almost the longest submission so far, but:

- It works for any number of digits of Pi.
- It removes all the required ASCII characters and the line break, without splitting the words in those places.
- It handles 0-digits in Pi correctly (as 10-letter words)

Comment: if it works for number of digits of Pi you get a 0.8 bonus

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 - 129

Doesn't account for punctuation:

```
import math
f=lambda p:all(1if len(p.split(' ')[i])!=int(str(math.pi).replace('.','')[i])else 1for i in range(len(p.split(' '))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python - <s>130 127</s> *116* - 17 digits of pi

As in [@flawr 's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/38267/31300), `Law ' s fine` and `Law's fine` both return True.

Thanks to [@Emil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29703/emil) for removing 12 characters from the program.

```
import re
f=lambda x:all(j==int("31415926535897932"[i])for i,j in enumerate([len(s)for s in re.findall("[\w]+",x)]))
```

Comment: You can save 12 characters by not saving `l` in a variable and by defining the function using lambda.

Answer (score 1):

### Java, 185

```
boolean f(String...s){s=s[0].replaceAll("\\W","~").replaceAll("~+","~").split("~");for(int i=0;i<s.length;){if(s[i].length()!=(int)(Math.PI*Math.pow(10,i++)%10))return 0>1;}return 1>0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## python 3, 17 digits of pi, 104

```
import re;f=lambda s:all(map(int.__eq__, map(int, '31415926535897932'), map(len,re.findall('[\w]+',s))))
```

Comment: You can replace the `;` with a newline for readability. Also, a number of spaces can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

### T-SQL <s>488</s> 383

And now for a large T-SQL solution :)

```
CREATE FUNCTION F(@s VARCHAR(MAX))RETURNS CHAR(6) AS BEGIN DECLARE @ CHAR='T',@p VARCHAR(50)='31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751',@i INT=0WHILE @='T'AND @s<>''BEGIN SET @i=PATINDEX('%[^a-z0-9]%',@s)IF @i=0RETURN'#True'IF @i-1<>LEFT(@p,1)RETURN'#False'SET @p=STUFF(@p,1,1,'')SET @s=STUFF(@s,1,@i,'')SET @s=STUFF(@s,1,PATINDEX('%[a-z0-9]%',@s)-1,'')END RETURN'#True'END
```

<s>This creates an inline table valued function that uses a recursive CTE to detect word boundaries.</s>

Creates a scalar function that chews it's way through the words and PI to 31 decimals (first 0).
It is called in the following way

```
SELECT dbo.f('SQL I golf, a large procedure is normal. Hefty not terse') --#True
```

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 40

```
"
,.'\"?!;:"{-}/S%{,PAV#*iA%=V):V}/]0#)!
```

It's unclear what is meant by "any kind of punctuation"; this solution removes the `,.'"?!;;` characters.

Answer (score 0):

## Bash and unix tools, 111

```
f() { grep ^"$(echo "$@"|grep -Po '[\w]+'|xargs -n1 sh -c 'echo ${#0}'|xargs|tr -d ' ')"<<<31415926535897932;
```

Answer (score 0):

**NodeJS 32 digits 230 Bytes**

I can't get it shorter with JS :D

```
var p = "31415926535897932384626433832795", i = 0;
console.log(process.argv[2].split(/[\s,.]+/).every(function(w) {
    if (parseInt(p.charAt(i)) !== w.length) {
        return false;
    }
    i++;
    return true;
}) ? 'True' : 'False');
```

Comment: remove whitespace.